# ubuntu systemd no such file or directory

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-18.04

I have a freshly installed system on Ubuntu 18.
After installing the package for memcached, I'm not able to start the service via

```
service memcached start
```

or

```
systemctl start memcached.service
```

syslog shows

```
memcached.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No such file or directory
memcached.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Failed to start memcached daemon.
```

The weird thing is: everything works fine when I start memcached directly with

```
/usr/bin/memcached -u memcache -d
```

or

```
/usr/share/memcached/scripts/systemd-memcached-wrapper /etc/memcached.conf
```

(the latter is configured as `ExecStart` in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/memcached.service`)

strace on `service`or `systemctl` does not really reveal which file/resource is missing.

Comment: Which user is defined to run the memcached service?

Comment: @Lenniey In /etc/memcached.conf "-u memcache" is set.

Comment: Did you use `sudo` for `systemctl start memcached.service`?

Comment: No, I did it as `root`.

Comment: Output of `systemctl status memcached.service` and `journalctl` after a failed start?

Comment: Just what I posted under "syslog". We'll reinstall the machine, as I've also installed Apache, and after a clean installation run into the same issue.